# Best way to observe changes to SQL table or query in c#

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have the following repository method...

```
IEnumerable<Client> repo.GetActiveClients();
```

What is the best way to periodically call this method and observe changes to the resulting enumerable list?

I am aware that **RX** provides `.ToObservable()`, which simplifies responding to changes in collection through subscriptions, but from examples I've seen, I can't work out how best to handle the polling and periodic calling of the method which will change the contents on the collection in the first place?

Comment: why you don't cache results and the second time only compare old results with new results? ... btw scenarios like this are candidates to start using EventSourcing or CQRS pattern

Comment: >>>caching<<< - So I'd still need to manually call the repository method on some sort of timer.  I had imagined that this is the sort of thing that RX would facilitate behind the scenes - oh well! thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something in your question, I think this is the best option:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15.0))
        .Select(x => repo.GetActiveClients())
        .Subscribe(clients =>
        {
            /* do something with the `clients` */
        });
```

Simple.

Comment: Yes, Simple when you know it :)  - It was the `Interval` clause I was looking for, and the exact syntax and way to combine it with the other clauses. Many Thanks.